# Last Modified By not matching history

Tags: history-tracking

We have found a number of contacts where the Last Modified By is a specific user, but the Contact History shows the actions at that time as being done by 'Automated Process'.  Under what circumstances would something like this happen?

Answer (score 0):

It was last modified by Salesforce when it does System Level changes. Why is Salesforce touching your stuff? Between last week's outage and the upcoming release this weekend I think the reason most likely lies there.

From the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000227314&type=1):

> This is a normal and expected part of how Salesforce maintains an organization. The user exists at the time that an organization is created and may be used by Salesforce to make automated system-level changes in the course of providing services and features present in an organization.